# Unity Particle System - single playing particle on hit

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

OK, I have a particle which is prefabed as it appears on the left of the image below.

[image: Comparison]

The left side is the result of the projectile code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float velocity;
    [SerializeField] float acceleration;
    new Collider2D collider;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask targetLayer;
    [SerializeField] float lifetime;
    [SerializeField] float damage;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem HitEffect;

    public event Action<Projectile,Collider2D> OnHit;

    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            return sr.color;
        }
        set
        {
            sr.color = value;
        }
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        collider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lifetime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifetime <=0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void SetTargetMask(LayerMask _mask)
    {
        targetLayer = _mask;
    }
    public void SetDamage(float amount)
    {
        this.damage = amount;
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        var _hitEffect = Instantiate(HitEffect.gameObject, transform).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        if (!_hitEffect.isPlaying) _hitEffect.Play();
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        collider.isTrigger = true;
        sr.enabled = false;
        Damageable othersDamage;
        other.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Damageable>(out othersDamage);
        //Debug.Log("dmg not null: " + (othersDamage != null)  + "; presumed layer:" + other.gameObject.layer + "; actual layer:" + targetLayer.value);
        if (othersDamage != null && other.gameObject.layer == targetLayer.value)
        {
            OnHit?.Invoke(this,other.collider);
            othersDamage.HandleDamage(damage);
        }
        Destroy(this.gameObject,HitEffect.main.duration);
    }
}
```

So, the idea is to have the particle as it appears on the left at each contact point, play, and vanish.
Instead, I have a non-animated particle that floats off after hitting the target.

What am I missing to get to play the single explosion at point, and how to get the sub particle to play properly.

Comment: If you change time to really slow it down. Perhaps you have parented the particles to the object you are on and have destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing to get to play the single explosion at point

Either stop the rigidbody completely:

```
rb.angularVelocity = Vector2.zero;
rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
```

Alternately, unparent the hit effect from the projectile, and destroy it after a delay

```
_hitEffect.transform.SetParent(null);
Destroy(_hitEffect.gameObject,afterDelay);
```